# Django 1.10 authentication on all apps

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

My Django project is a single web site which has the following directory structure:

```
project
-- main_folder
   -- settings.py
   -- views.py
   -- urls.py [1]
   -- ...
-- app_folder
   -- views.py
   -- urls.py [2]
   -- ...
-- not_app_folder
   -- views.py
   -- urls.py [3]
   -- ...
-- manage.py
```

I use this code in `urls.py [1]` to authenticate a user:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login),
    ...
]
```

I have a code that successfully worked on all of my web-site pages with `Django 1.9` (a template method `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` returns `true` on all pages).

After upgrade authentication works well on all urls from `urls.py [1]` file, but when I move to pages mentioned in `urls.py [2]` (it is an application directory) or `urls.py [3]` (it is a simple directory), template method `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` returns `false` (I have the same template for all pages).

What has changed in `Django 1.10` and how to keep authentication alive on any page of a web-site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should be very careful when upgrading Django. Many functions become deprecated but are still working and not as expected.

This code worked fine in Django 1.9:

```
vars = RequestContext(request, {'key': 'value'})
return render_to_response('template.html', vars)
```

But `render_to_response` will be deprecated soon and for Django 1.10 you should write:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'key': 'value'})
```

There was no difference in how many apps or `views.py` files you have. User authentication works properly now.

Answer (score -1):

I use this middleware I found at https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2845/.
It even have regular expression whitelist on URLs(`LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS`)

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# django dependencies
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.conf import settings

# python dependencies
from re import compile

#---#

EXEMPT_URLS = [compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [compile(expr) for expr in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

#---#

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    """
    Middleware that requires a user to be authenticated to view any page other
    than LOGIN_URL. Exemptions to this requirement can optionally be specified
    in settings via a list of regular expressions in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS (which
    you can copy from your urls.py).

    Requires authentication middleware and template context processors to be
    loaded. You'll get an error if they aren't.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user'), ("The Login Required middleware "
            "requires authentication middleware to be installed. Edit "    
            "your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert "
            "'django.contrib.auth.middlware.AuthenticationMiddleware'. "  
            "If that doesn't work, ensure your "
            "TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting includes "
            "'django.core.context_processors.auth'.")
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
            if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):            
                path = request.get_full_path()
                return redirect_to_login(path, settings.LOGIN_URL,
                                         REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME)
```

Just put it after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.*AuthenticationMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings. If you don't have it there you have to add it.

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ...
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'sis_tools.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware', # <-- HERE
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

The white list works like the `urls.py` so you can use it like this:

```py
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = ( r'^about.html$', r'^legal/',)
```

This allows user to visit page `sample.com/about.html` and everything in section `sample.com/legal/*`

---

Also you have to set in your settings [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-url) to your login page like this:

```py
LOGIN_PAGE = "/accounts/login"
```

Also it's handy to set [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) url where to jump if user enters the site on login page.

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```